# Password policies remain after deleting profile?

Tags: deployment, metadata-api, profile, security, sdlc

I deleted a profile via the Metadata API, and it did not delete its associated password policies.  I cannot find the policies anywhere in the UI, but when I pull from production (or any sandbox refreshed post profile deletion), the file still appears: `Sales_Conga_Pilot_profilePasswordPolicy1520454061559.profilePasswordPolicy`.  The "Sales_Conga_Pilot" profile no longer exists.

I'm pulling profile password policies using the '*' among other things in a pretty comprehensive retrieve package:

```
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>ProfilePasswordPolicy</name>
</types>
```

Of course now, when I try to deploy this file, it errors out.  This is understandably causing a bit of a nuisance for our SDLC processes, since we have to manually avoid committing it to git every time we make changes.

Does anyone have any idea how this happened?  Or a way to fix the problem?